# Parametros en un href... con ASP NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Tengo la necesidad de enviar parámetros por un `href` en ASP.NET MVC. El problema lo tengo al poner el segundo párametro a enviar; esos parametros a enviar son datos recibidos en la vista con un `ViewData`

```
<li><a href="~/Servicios?numpagina=@ViewData["Pagina"]&cliente=@ViewData["ClienteFiltro"]">Servicios a Clientes</a></li>
```

me genera el link

```
localhost/Servicios?numpagina=5&cliente=
```

es decir, no agrega el segundo parámetro, pero ese parametro sí tiene datos, ya lo verifiqué.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que guardas en `ViewData["ClienteFiltro"]`?

Comment: Hola, el Id del Cliente que esta filtrado en la vista Index, esto para que al hacer click en el href regresar a la vista index e ir a la pagina en la que estaba, asi como solo mostrar los servicios de ese cliente

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Intenta utilizar `Url.Action`

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Metodo","Controlador", new { numpagina = @ViewData["Pagina"], cliente= @ViewData["ClienteFiltro"]} )">Servicios a Clientes</a>
```